# Why hibernate's get(classname, index) returns an object instead of a "classname" instance?

Tags: java, hibernate

I know "Object" is the Super class of all objects, but why does not Hibernate return directly a type "classname" instead?

Why the Hibernate ORM make us do a cast?

Specially, I read Hibernate returns a "proxy class", so lazy loading can be used in order to save memory (and time), how can we be obtaining a "proxy class" if we are EXPLICTLY doing a cast to the "real" class (not the proxy)???

I mean, if a I have for example a Country class:

```
public class Country {

    private int id;
    private String name;

 public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
```

And with Hibernate I do:

```
Country country = (Country) session.get(Country.class, 1);
```

How can I be getting a "proxy" if I just did a cast to Country?

Comment: I am pretty sure the proxy class extends your class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casting is not a runtime process that transforms an object of a certain type into an object of a different type.

Casting is simply advising the compiler that the returned object can actually be treated as a more specific (like in your case) one. Thanks to that you can use more detailed methods / api.

Once the code is compiled and run, all taht information is obsolete.

Comment: Got it! Thank you!

I thought the cast was in fact "transforming" something, but being like you say just advising the compiler how the object (whichever the class) can be treated, it makes a lot more sense!

Answer (score 0):

The signature of Hibernate 5 Session's get method is...

```
<T> T get(Class<T> entityType, Serializable id);
```

... which means it returns the correct class and doesn't make you cast it. That means something else is "wrong" with your code. Are you using an older version of Hibernate?

It may return a proxy, in which case that proxy will effectively be a subclass of your entity type.